# What automorphism cannot be extended when the extension is not normal?

Tags: galois-theory, normal-extension

As I understand it, if we have an automorphism $\phi : K \rightarrow K$, and a finite normal extension $N/K$, $\phi$ can always be extended to an automorphism of $N$. But what happens if $N/K$ is not a normal extension? If for instance I consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$, what automorphism $\phi$ could not be extended?

Comment: That's not the correct example as $Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}))$ is trivial. Let $f= \prod_{j=1}^4 (x-e_j)$ irreducible and assume $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)/\mathbb{Q}) = A_4$. So switching $e_1,e_2$ and $e_3,e_4$ is in $Aut(\mathbb{Q}(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4))$ and then there is no automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ extending the automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(e_1,e_2)$ switching $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Comment: What are the $e_i$'s? Could it be $e_1=\sqrt{2}$, $e_2=\sqrt{3}$, $e_3=\sqrt{5}$, $e_4=\sqrt{7}$?

Comment: Do you really think there exists an automorphism switching $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ ?

Comment: No, I don't. So they could be the 4-th root of unity?

Comment: $A_4$ is the alternating group $\subset S_4$, it is "complicated" and non-abelian nor of order $2$

Comment: I still don't get it : what are the $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ concretely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the field $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)$ with its nontrivial automorphism $\phi:\sqrt2\mapsto-\sqrt2$. Consider also the quadratic (and thus normal) extension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2\,)=N\supset K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)$. As you see, there is no extension of $\phi$ to $N$. So your premise is false.

I’ve been considering writing one last paper, an examination of this problem in more generality.

Comment: this is a nice example, and I understand it shows that my premise is false, but what condition I should add in order for it to be true?

Comment: I suppose that if you’re thinking about number fields exclusively, you could get around the problem by looking at the larger field $N^c$ that is the normal closure of $N$ over $\Bbb Q$. I think there’d be no such escape clause if there was no absolute field beneath $K$, as in cases when $K$ has positive transcendence degree over the prime field.